# Pandas: Groupby sum

Tags: python, pandas

Partially Solved!

This is my dataframe (a lot of rows):

```
           amount   catcode     date    feccandid   type
date                    
2014-05-15  1000    E1600   05/15/2014  H8TX22107   24K
2013-10-22  5000    G4600   10/22/2013  H4TX28046   24K
2014-03-26    4     C2100   03/26/2014  H0MO07113   24Z
2014-05-06  1000    F1100   05/06/2014  H0OH06189   24K
```

I would like to return a column that groups by `date (per year)` and sums the amount per `catcode`, and per `type` for each `feccandaid`. Is think this is the way to do this in Pandas. If curious, please check my code:

```
 f = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(level='date', freq='A'), 'catcode', 'type', 'feccandid'])[['amount']].sum()
```

This is what is returns:

```
                                       amount
date    catcode     type    feccandid   
1915-12-31  A5000   24K     H6TX08100   1000
1916-12-31  T6100   24K     H8CA52052   500
1954-12-31  H3100   24K     S8AK00090   1000
```

I'm not very experienced with Pandas and am not sure if this is the result that I think it is. 
I still need to edit the outliers in `date`. I have the following code for that:

```
df = df[(df['date'] > '2007-01-01') & (cs['date'] < '2014-12-31')]
```

But when I use it, it returns an empty dataset.

Comment: In your code to filter by date: `df['date'] > '2007-01-01'` is comparing the data in the `'date'` column with a string, which will not give you the result you're looking for. Have a look at the pandas docs for [Time Series / Date functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html). If your data has a [DateTimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex) then it should be fairly straightforward to specifiy the year range using [`truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#truncating-fancy-indexing).

Comment: Thank you! I applied you code `df.truncate(before='2007/01/01', after='2014/12/31')` and it returns a `KeyError: "Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00')"` error. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: Is your data sorted by the DateTimeIndex? From what I can tell, that can sometimes cause errors with slicing. See [`pd.DataFrame.sort_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

Comment: Yes. It is sorted by DateTime Index